# application to start stop website on IIS 5.1

Tags: c#, iis-5

I'm trying to write two applications to start and stop web sites in IIS 5.1, and webSites and applications pull in IIS 7.5. For IIS 7.5 there is Microsoft.Web.Administration where are methods for do it, but I don't know how do it in IIS version 5.1. Is some library to do it? If not, how can I do it?

## edit

IIS 5.1 works on windows XP